# Mongo Db extended library for Robot Framework returns wrong records

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, robotframework

I have extended MongoDbLibrary for Robot Framework for making available usage of .skip(),.take() and .order()

```
def _retrieve_mongodb_records_ex(self, dbName, dbCollName, recordJSON, sorting, skip=0, take=None, fields=[], returnDocuments=False):
    db = None
    try:
        dbName = str(dbName)
        dbCollName = str(dbCollName)
        criteria = dict(json.loads(recordJSON))
        db = self._dbconnection['%s' % (dbName,)]
        coll = db['%s' % (dbCollName)]
        if fields:
            results = coll.find(criteria, fields)
        else:
            results = coll.find(criteria)
        if sorting:
            results = results.sort(sorting)
        if (skip):
            skip = int(skip)
        if skip > 0:
            results = results.skip(skip)
        if take:
            results = results.limit(int(take))
        if returnDocuments:
            return list(results)
        else:
            response = ''
            for d in results:
                response = '%s%s' % (response, d.items())
            return response
    finally :
        if db :
            self._dbconnection.end_request()
```

I have a test on python:

```
mongo.connect_to_mongodb("mongodb://somehost", 27017)
result = mongo.retrieve_some_records("MMMongoDB", "importjob", "{\"Status\" : 9}", [("DateCreated", -1)], "0", "1", True)
```

This test returns correct data

In robot framework I'm using this method in my keyword:

```
Get Some Mongo Records With Order And Limit
[Arguments]    ${MongoHostProp}    ${MongoPortProp}    ${MongoDbNameProp}    ${MongoCollProp}    ${QueryProp}    ${Sorting}
...    ${Skip}    ${Take}
Connect To MongoDB    ${MongoHostProp}    ${MongoPortProp}
${records}=    Retrieve Some Records    ${VAR_ImportMongoDbName}    ${VAR_ImportJobMongoCollName}    ${QueryProp}    ${Sorting}    ${Skip}
...    ${Take}    true
Disconnect From Mongodb
[Return]    ${records}
```

But this keyword returns first item that matches with ${QueryProp} ignoring ${Sorting}.

I compared the parameters that I'm send to this python method - they are equal. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason why pymongo does not treat sorting parameter as key-value pair is the RobotFramework which tends to turn every value into string.

Your Python code should check whether the value is string and evaluate it to turn it back into list of key-value pairs.

```js
    if isinstance(sorting, string_types):
                    sorting = eval(sorting)
```

Pymongo interprets string as a single sorting key and turns it into pair by adding 'pymongo.ASCENDING' which is the default direction.